# getElementById() display from several variables

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I want to display via document.getElementById from an external javascript file a compilation of links to social networks depending on the language version of my website. The problem is it works perfectly for the first ID ("sociallv") but doesn't work for others ("socialen" and "socialru") if I use them separately on a webpage. What should I change?

```js
/* Social networks start */

var start = "<div class='social justify-content-between'>"

var end = "</div>"

var facebook = "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/maggitekstils.lv' title='Facebook' rel='noreferrer' target='_blank'><div class='social-button facebook'></div>"; 

var draugiem = "<a href='https://www.draugiem.lv/maggitekstils.lv' title='Draugiem' rel='noreferrer' target='_blank'><div class='social-button draugiem'></div>"; 

var youtube = "<a href='https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2H9dhm1Nzw3i4wveNTgHnQ/playlists' title='YouTube' rel='noreferrer' target='_blank'><div class='social-button youtube'></div></a>"; 

document.getElementById("sociallv").innerHTML = start + facebook + draugiem + youtube + end;

document.getElementById("socialen").innerHTML = start + facebook + youtube + end;

document.getElementById("socialru").innerHTML = start + facebook + youtube + end;

/* Social networks end */
```

```html
<div class="social-media" id="socialen"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of concatenating snippets of HTML, you could use [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if there are any errors in your JS Console ?

For Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open

For Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

I supspect that the execution of your Javascript is abborted because you're trying to set a value for a property on an object which does not exists and therefore the blocks

```js
document.getElementById("socialen").innerHTML = start + facebook + youtube + end;

document.getElementById("socialru").innerHTML = start + facebook + youtube + end;
```

are never reached. You should always do a check if the queried element exists or not:

```js
// ...

if ( document.getElementById("socialen") ) {
  document.getElementById("socialen").innerHTML = start + facebook + youtube + end;
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In the html provided, you only have an element with id `socialen` which is why when you set the innerHTML of `socialen` it works. However `socialru` and `sociallv` aren't html elements therefore its not actually setting anything.

If you add the following to your html, you should get the expected result

```html
<div class="social-media" id="sociallv"></div>
<div class="social-media" id="socialru"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I know if I put all 3 IDs on one webpage it works perfectly. But the question is how I can use can I use only one of the IDs per webpage?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by webpage? Do you mean different HTML files or different body sections?